# Laravel 8 collection sort by asc

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection so i wnat order it for asc.How i do it?I know elequent has sortbydesc method but it hasn't sortbyasc

```
 @foreach($item->sortByAsc('date') as $k=>$v)
```

Comment: How about `sortBy`?

Comment: `sortBy()` method defaults to ascending sort. You can use `sortByDesc()` if the opposite is needed. There is [a list of available methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) in the documentation.

Comment: Also note, `sortBy` and `sortByDesc` are Collection methods. If you want to do a sort at the Database Level, then you'd use `orderBy('column', 'direction')` on a Query Builder instance.